# Add Checkbox to datatables JQuery service side

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I'm server side I want to add a checkbox who returns true or false when the checkbox is checked or not. But I don't know how to add the event on change to my checkbox in the table and send the Boolean to my data. And I want to set the checkbox next to the global search.

**HTML**

```
<table id="searchlog" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">Case Sensitive :
    <input type='checkbox' id='idCaseSensitive' />
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>COL1</th>
            <th>COL2</th>
            <th>COL3</th>
            <th>COL4</th>
            <th>COL5</th>
            <th>COL6</th>
            <th>COL7</th>
            <th>COL8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchlog').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        aaSorting: [
            [1, 'desc']
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: '/mypath/...',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                caseSensitive: true // I want the checkbox's return on this parameter
            }
        }
    });
    $('#idCaseSensitive').change(function (data) {
        if (this.checked) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Could you help me to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with a function who returns the flag variable and I use it in the data caseSensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var flag=false;    
$('#idCaseSensitive').change(function (data) {
            if ($(this).attr("checked")==true) {
                flag=true;
            } else {
                flag=false;
            }
        });
    $('#searchlog').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        aaSorting: [
            [1, 'desc']
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: '/mypath/...',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                caseSensitive: flag; // I want the checkbox's return on this parameter
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes but I want this return in the Ajax data "caseSensitive"

Comment: Now check above, I have taken a 'flag' variable which can store the boolean types of values

Comment: it doesn't work. The data isn't sent. Maybe I should reload the table ?